# can we use TCRT5000 sensor instead of IR proximity sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, ir, proximity, distance

I am planning to make a human following robot which requires two IR proximity sensors.
I already have two TCRT5000 sensor. Can I use it instead of it?

Comment: your question is like `I am baking an apple cake that requires two apples. I already have two yellow apples. Can I use them instead?`

Comment: I meant is TCRT5000 different from regular ir proximity sensor?

Comment: what's a regular IR proximity sensor?

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/VEEROBOT-Infrared-Proximity-Obstacle-Detecting/dp/B0115NCT4U/ref=asc_df_B0115NCT4U/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397008884140&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11247381740971132298&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9297848&hvtargid=pla-391398992335&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi

Comment: your question is off topic here because it is not about the arduino ... it is also vague, and is not answerable until you provide some operational requirements, such as detection distance

Comment: An IR distance sensor is mainly an IR LED and an IR phototransistor.  Thats what the TCRT5000 is. Though the ready to use boards incorporate more electronics to output an analog voltage according  to the signal (rough measurement of distance) and a digital output using a threshold (controllable via the potentiometer). If you use the TCRT5000 you might need to add more electronics to actually get the desired results. Most likely you would need an amp circuit to get a good signal to measure